# Alternative to 'hype' for an academic paper

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am working on an academic paper, and I want to describe the scientific community's hype regarding a certain technology. The word 'hype' is concise and describes exactly what I mean, but I'm not sure the word has the proper tone for an academic document. Is there an alternative term or concise phrase that gets the same idea across in a more academic tone?

Comment: I'm not as academic as the link on your profile shows you are, but my thinking is, if it can be found in all these federal court cases ([http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=hype&as_sdt=3%2C44&as_ylo=&as_vis=0][1]), then maybe it's OK in an academic setting as well.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that simply means that something is being promoted aggressively, or one with the sometimes-more-negative connotation?

Answer (score 4):

*[Aggrandizement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aggrandizement)* ("act of aggrandizing", ie, of making to appear great or greater) may serve, or perhaps *[exaltation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exaltation)* ("the act of exalting or raising high"), *[glorification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glorification)* ("act of glorifying", particularly in sense of making something appear more glorious than it is), *[deification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deification)* ("act of deifying", ie, of treating as worthy of worship or regarding as a deity).   Less formally, consider *[kowtowing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kowtow)*, *advertising*, or  *buzzing*.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe *buildup* would work, if there is a sense of increasing attention being paid to the technology.

Or perhaps "the scientific community's *enthusiasm* for a technology is..."

Answer (score 2):

How about *aggressive promotion* or *overblown promotion*?

Answer (score 1):

I think *hype* is perfectly fine, even in a formal academic context -- it is the best word for the job... If you want to tip a hat to the formality, consider italicising it, or putting it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

What about *increasing popularity*?

(Maybe that doesn't carry a negative enough connotation for what you want, but that inference could be handled by the accompanying context.)

Answer (score -2):

What about using the word from which "hype" probably originated — hyperbole?

Comment: That could *not* under any circumstances suit the context.